# Problems moving a div with hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can I send the positions of the main container - yellow color - (left, top, width, height) to a child component - lead color - and receive these values as parameters.

The parameters are updated by a resize event

Currently, the parameters sent arrive as null and are never updated by clicking on the lead container that is where I need them to calculate the actual position.

Click  [for example](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-cookies-4x0w5?fontsize=14)

Now it works correctly

Comment: What you want to perform? I think you are on track

Comment: This is really interesting. Your margin prop is accessible by all other methods in BoxDiv.js, with the exception of `handleMouseDown`. Your margin properties ARE actually being sent to the child component. But for a reason I haven't yet been able to find, your method can't access the prop (or the variable you set for it).

Comment: I'd double check your `useCallback` functions. Make sure the second param is correct so your functions are updated / re-created when new margin props come in

Comment: When doing the resize if the varibale "margin" (of Principal.js) is loaded but when I press the click (in BoxDiv.js) handleMouseDown this variable becomes null.
This is vital for the calculation of the position of the box, that is why it moves lower.

Comment: Now I added handleMouseDown in BoxDiv.js in the second parameter **[state.isDragging]** and it improved, but the first click still doesn't get the value.

Comment: first try to remove the useCallback wrapper just to make sure it works how you want it to. Then add it back in and make sure it updates that function the same.

Comment: "John Ruddell" I was right, I found the solution by changing handleMouseDown in BoxDiv.js the second parameter must be ** [marginParent] **. Now it works correctly. Already modify the code. Thank you all. Greetings from Peru.